# Store response value into global object. Success but didn't work

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, fetch

I cannot really understand how JS run. Can you explain it for me(at least, give me some keyword).

```js
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res=> {
    dosth(res)
})

function dosth(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.results[0])
}
```

here it come:
[here it come:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCSP5.png)

but when i change my way.

```js
let myobj = {}
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res=> {

    for(let i=0;i<res.results.length;i++){
        myobj[i]=res.results[i]
    }
    dosth(myobj)
})

function dosth(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data["0"])
}
```

it still works: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6qUm.png)

but now :

```js
let myobj = {}
fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res=> {

    for(let i=0;i<res.results.length;i++){
        myobj[i]=res.results[i]
    }
})
dosth(myobj)
function dosth(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data["0"])
}
```

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFqzR.png)
DevTools can log entire obj, but not the property specified.I think it must be

```js
> {} / devtools of chromes display an object with properties.(i think its must be an empty obj.
> undefined
```

Can you explain it for me?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs synchronously normally. In the 3rd case where you receive empty object because the `fetch` call is asynchronous call i.e. why `dosth(myobj)` got called before your `fetch` call completed and will give you the response. So, it is good to call `dosth(myobj)`, inside the response block of `fetch` call where you receive the response data, otherwise the object would be empty.

Reasons for  :

`> {} //empty object.` => It is coming from your 1st line i.e. `let myobj = {}`
`> undefined` => as regarding `data["0"]`, data is empty object with no property.

Comment: actually, it is not empty obj, i console log its, still have data, but when i try to access to property its is undefined. I capture my devtools, check the link and you will know why i asked that.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript runs synchronously normally. but,the fetch call is asynchronous call.

dosth function should be after for directly Like this:

```js
   let myobj2 = {}
    fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res=> {

        for(let i=0;i<res.results.length;i++){
            myobj2[i]=res.results[i]
        }
        dosth(myobj2)// here
    })
 //dosth(myobj2) not here
    function dosth(data){
        console.log('ab2',data)
        console.log('ab3',data["0"])
    }
```